# why can't i add front.css to my frontpage.php

Tags: functions, theme-development, css, frontpage

My function in functions.php

```
function adding_front_style(){
  if(is_front_page()){
  wp_enqueue_style('front',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/front.css');
}else{
  //some code
}
}
add_action('init','adding_front_style');
```

My front-page.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class = "search">
  <?php get_search_form() ?>
</div>
```

My front.css

```
  .search{
  background-color: blue; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong choice of hook, `Init` hook Fires after WordPress has finished loading, so what you have thought is right. But `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook is required to load JavaScript and CSS.

Replace line `add_action('init','adding_front_style');` with
`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','adding_front_style');`

Comment: but I added **style.css** using init

Comment: I can help if you add code snippet here.

Comment: `function adding_style_scripts(){
  wp_enqueue_style('style',get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');
}
add_action('init','adding_style_scripts');`

Comment: Check your functions.php. It Seems, `style.css` is loaded from `functions.php` using `wp_enqueue_style( '<your-theme-slug>'-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );`. Anyway this is the standard method to load 'style.css' `wp_enqueue_style( '<your-theme-slug>'-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong action for to add the script, you're should use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook instead of `init`

```
function adding_front_style() {
    if( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'front', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/front.css');
    } else {
        //some code
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','adding_front_style');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hooking the enqueue in to 'init' you need to use wp_enqueue_scripts.

```
function adding_front_style(){
  if(is_front_page()){
     wp_enqueue_style('front',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/front.css');
  } else {
   //some code
  }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','adding_front_style');
```

It's also worth noting that if you are using a child theme at all you'd be better off using get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead of get_template_directory_uri(), as with the latter your child theme won't override any styles in the parent theme.